# p:tree drag and drop with multiple nodes

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, tree

Is there anyway to make this possible.
If I try to drag and drop two nodes in my tree, both are dropped but only one of them will be updated in the view.
Only after reloading the page the second is at the dropped place.

I think the problem is that the event is only invoked one time.
But I'm not able to update the tree from the backing bean.

my .xhtml

```
        <p:tree id="navigationTree"
            value="#{testCaseDefinitionView.tree.root}" var="node"
            selectionMode="multiple"
            selection="#{testCaseDefinitionView.tree.selectedNodes}"
            dynamic="true"
            draggable="#{testCaseDefinitionView.isInTreeEditMode()}"
            droppable="#{testCaseDefinitionView.isInTreeEditMode()}"

            onNodeClick="scrollPosition.save()">
            <p:ajax event="select"
                listener="#{testCaseDefinitionController.onNodeSelect}"
                update=":testautomatContent:treeContentButtons, :testautomatContent:mainPanel"
                oncomplete="scrollPosition.restore()" />
            <p:ajax event="unselect"
                update=":testautomatContent:treeContentButtons, :testautomatContent:mainPanel" />
            <p:ajax event="dragdrop"
                listener="#{testCaseDefinitionController.onDragDrop}"
                oncomplete="markSelectedTreeElements()"
                update=":testautomatContent"
                process="@form"/>
            <p:ajax event="expand"
                listener="#{testCaseDefinitionController.nodeExpand}" />
            <p:ajax event="collapse"
                listener="#{testCaseDefinitionController.nodeCollapse}" />
            <p:treeNode type="TEST_GROUP">
                <p:outputPanel id="testGroupNode" style="padding: 1px;">
                    <p:outputPanel id="configIcon" styleClass="config-icon-box"
                        style="display: inline-block;">
                        <p:outputPanel
                            styleClass="#{iconController.getConfigIcon(node.configType).getStyleSutConfig()} boxsizing-border" />
                        <p:outputPanel
                            styleClass="#{iconController.getConfigIcon(node.configType).getStyleTcConfig()} boxsizing-border" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel styleClass="nowrap" style="display: inline-block;">
                        <h:outputText id="testGroupNodeLabel" value="&nbsp;#{node.name}" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:treeNode>
            <p:treeNode type="TEST_CASE">
                <p:outputPanel id="testCaseNode" style="padding: 1px;">
                    <span class="#{iconController.getTypeIconStyle(node.type).small()}" />
                    <h:outputText id="testCaseNodeLabel" styleClass="nowrap" value="&nbsp;#{node.name}" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>
```

and the onDragDrop in the Bean

```
public void onDragDrop(TreeDragDropEvent event) {
    DragAndDropState dragAndDropState = DragAndDropState.FAIL;
    nodesToDrag = Arrays.asList(view.getTree().getSelectedNodes());
    for (TreeNode nodes: nodesToDrag) {
        dragAndDropState = view.getTree().updateDragDrop(nodes, event.getDropNode());
        logger.warn(event.getComponent().toString());
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":testautomatContent");
    }
    if (!(dragAndDropState.equals(DragAndDropState.SUCCESS)) && !(dragAndDropState.equals(DragAndDropState.MULTISELECTION))) {
        showDragAndDropMessage(dragAndDropState.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your PF version? And no, I don't think multiple drag/drop is supported

Comment: I'm on 5.2. I could work with a possibility to force reloading the page.